# How to make a function inside render() wait for component did mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello I want my function called Monday() to wait for ComponentDidMount() before being called inside my render()
my component takes the ID of my student from the path and then runs into another backend route which returns an array of courses the student has.

and then that array of arrays gets divided into smaller arrays where every array has a course name course day and course time.

I want Monday function to display the name but it returns undefined because it gets called before my ComponentDidmount().

This is my code`

```js
  componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
        if(this.props.match.params.id==='100')
        window.location='/passerror'
         axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/'+this.props.match.params.id)
          .then(async response => {
            console.log(response.data.sections)
              this.setState({
                listA:response.data.sections.map(sections => sections)
              })
              console.log(this.state.listA) 
              
              this.sortLists()
          })
          .catch((error) => {
          })
   }
     sortLists(x){
        console.log(x[0])
        if(this.state.listA[0]){ 
               this.state.listB.push(this.state.listA[0].name,this.state.listA[0].day,this.state.listA[0].time)

         }
         if(this.state.listA[1]){ 
            this.state.listC.push(this.state.listA[1].name,this.state.listA[1].day,this.state.listA[1].time)

      }
      if(this.state.listA[2]){ 
        this.state.listD.push(this.state.listA[2].name,this.state.listA[2].day,this.state.listA[2].time)

    }
    if(this.state.listA[3]){ 
        this.state.listE.push(this.state.listA[3].name,this.state.listA[3].day,this.state.listA[3].time)

    } 

    console.log(this.state.listB.length,this.state.listC[0],this.state.listD,this.state.listE)
    }
    monday(e){
      console.log(this.state.listB[0])
      let coursename=this.state.listB[0];

    console.log(coursename)
      return(coursename)
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <Table striped bordered hover size="sm"style = {{width:"100vh",position: 'absolute', left: '50%', top: '60%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'}}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Day</th>
              <th>Monday</th>
              <th>Tuesday</th>
              <th>Wednesday</th>
              <th>Thursday</th>
              <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>8:00AM - 9:30AM</td>
              <td> {this.monday()}</td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>
        </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can't - `render` is always called before `componentDidMount`. You could display some fallback UI, eg a "loading" message of some kind, until the data has been fetched

Comment: how do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not manually change state like `this.state.listA[0] = xyz`, you need to use `this.setState`

You shouldn't manually make something wait for componentDidMount to complete.

When componentDidMount is called and the data fetching is complete, it will set the state and cause react to render again, during this render it should have picked up the new value. It works in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-matsumoto-ti9ot?file=/src/App.js

However, during the initial `render`, there is no data, so at this point you will need to display either a fallback value, or let it be empty until the data fetching is complete.

The sequence of operation goes like this:

1. React initial render with no data available
2. `componentDidMount` called, data fetching happens
3. data fetching async returns, setState with new data
4. state change causes react to update, and re-render
5. render with new state which has data.

Make sure you understand how react lifecycle works: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: ??? do you not see 'mock data' rendered on the right after the dataFetching function completes?

Comment: Of course it's initially going to return undefined, because there is no value there

Comment: i noticed but then how would the data i need be displayed ?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question, you cannot display data when there **is no data to be displayed**. I feel like you lack a basic understanding of react life cycle methods, rendering, and async operations. I recommend you read up on those first.

Comment: no i understand it but i might have explained it badly 
i know the componentDidMount comes after the render() so there is no data in my list and it returns undefined 
my quesion is how do i display the wanted data then ? or are you saying i can't ?

Comment: No, I don't think you understand. I updated my answer with the sequence of operation. please go read how react lifecycle works.

Comment: it's just that the second render also displays undefined

Comment: I just noticed that you are directly changing state, you should not modify react states, you need to use setState. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate